# SSRS Report Printing Incorrectly

Tags: sql, printing, reporting-services

I am trying to figure out why a row keeps on blowing up during printing. Here is an example:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VA2fB.jpg #2 is where it is getting extended.  As you can see it happens when the data continues on to the next page.  It is because of the columns on the right where the values are "Family" and "Mom".  If I remove those two columns, the report prints out fine.  Once I add them back in, the last row, no matter the row, expands dramatically if it is the leading row on the next page.

Things that I have already tried which have not worked:
- Disabling the option to have the cells increase or decrease in height.
- Tried increasing the height and width of the tablix
- Altered the data type and size to only 6 char for both columns on the left

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should include relevant data directly in the question to prevent link rot. You should also share the code that is creating this table. (Note, if this is done by an external tool, S.O. is not the appropriate forum.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the right of your outermost column and set its width to very small with no borders and background color(invisible). This may do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

have you try to have the same row height same as the above. 
try to set the row "**Can Shrink**" to false and "**Can Grow**" to false